# Incorrect table rendering

Tags: html, css, html-table

```
<table width="300" height=100 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td width="150" colspan="2" ></td>
   <td width="75"  colspan="1" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="75" colspan="1"></td>
   <td width="150" colspan="2"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td width="75" colspan="1"  ></td>
   <td width="150" colspan="2" ></td>
  </tr>
  <tr> 
   <td width="75" colspan="1" ></td>
   <td width="150" colspan="2" ></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

This table should looks like

[image]
<sub>(source: [rayz.ru](http://gridwizard.rayz.ru/images/correct.gif))</sub>

but in real

[image]
<sub>(source: [rayz.ru](http://gridwizard.rayz.ru/images/incorrect.gif))</sub>

**Is there any solutions?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Four things:

1. `colspan="1"` is not required. It is the default value;
2. You should favour CSS. What you're doing is deprecated;
3. You don't need a width on every cell. Just the first one (in each column) is sufficient; and
4. Use the `<col>` element to explicitly layout your columns.

For example:

```
#mytable { width: 300px; height: 100px; border: border-collapse: collapse; }
#mytable td { border: 1px solid none; }
```

with:

```
<table id="mytable">
<col style="width: 75px;">
<col style="width: 75px;">
<col style="width: 75px;">
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2">...</td>
   <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>...</td>
   <td colspan="2">...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2">...</td>
   <td>...</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>...</td>
   <td colspan="2">...</td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I suppose, giving the width in `td` style will work exactly the same, no need to define `col` separately like this. Just remove the `col' and it should work perfectly fine. What you say?

Comment: The problem with setting the widths in the TD elements in this case is that there is no middle column explicitly. It is implicitly defined by the colspans of the left and right columns. Using COL elements circumvents that problem.

Comment: I tried without `col`, its working like charm. Actually, I wrote the answer but then found you already answered that almost exactly the same I drafted. The only difference was I didn't put `col` tags, of course use the `colspan`. Just gave the width to `td` style. I was working in firefox, at least. Not sure about IE or others.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you only ever define two columns and colspan only works once enough columns to span are defined.

You can create a dummy row of 3 cells to define your structure, then the spanning will work.  However, your cellpadding and spacing will cause a slight gap at the top of your table, so I'd suggest applying padding to `<td>`'s vis css rather than directly in the table.  You can then hide your dummy column by not styling it.

```
<table width="300" height=100 cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2" border="1">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td width="100"></td>
   <td width="100"></td>
   <td width="100"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="2">e</td>
   <td colspan="1">e</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td colspan="1">e</td>
   <td colspan="2">e</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Another alternative is to create a proper table head (`<thead> ... </thead>`) where you label the columns and put the cells in there.

Comment: 3 columns are not required. Check out the correct form in the original question.